# finding out the firstrow values of <SelectListItem> in the controller before sending them to view MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

Im binding UsersList to a dropdownlist using a selectlistitem

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserId, new SelectList(Model.Users, "Value", "Text", Model.UserId))


public List<SelectListItem> Users { get; set; }


Public ActionResult LoadUsers()
{
UserModel usrModel=new UserModel();
usrModel.LoadUsers();
string firstUser=?
return view(usrModel);
}
```

Im binding UsersList to a dropdownlist using a selectlistitem

my requirement is when the user is sensing the Users to view from controller, i want to find out the value field of the User in first row, i.e before binding to the dropdownlist itself i want to find out who is the first User who will be selected in the dropdownlist when the page first loads

Comment: Use Model.Users.FirstOrDefault()

Comment: how can i get the value field from it?

Comment: Use Model.Users.FirstOrDefault().FieldYouWant

Comment: string Usr = objDailyEqp.Projects.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Value); im getting the error as cannot implicitly convert string to bool

Comment: Use FirstOrDefault().FieldYouWant where FieldYouWant is of Type string

Comment: thnku it worked fine..